# Scrolling on medium.com with Vimium

Tags: google-chrome

I use vimium on Google Chrome to be able to use j/k to scroll when I'm reading. I love reading on medium.com because of its great typography (readability). Vimium works on most pages but on medium.com I have to select the main content area before being able to use j/k.

Is there anyone who could think of a way to fix this? I know I've had the same problem on other sites as well but I can't remember which ones.

Comment: Hey @Marlun, were you able to solve the issue? I stumbled upon this, still can't scroll on Medium with Vimium enabled. :(

Comment: No, I asked on their issue tracker https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/426 but never got a response. I'm using Firefox a lot more now and the plugin VimFx seem to work on more pages (works fine on medium.com).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it myself, and I'm not seeing any obvious way to change any settings or perform any particular action (without the mouse) in order to get Vimium scrolling that page. This is likely an issue with Vimium itself misbehaving on a website that uses fancy Javascript. On Vimium's GitHub page you can find their [official issue tracker](https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues), and I recommend filing a new issue there about the problem (being sure to provide a link to medium.com for reference). I'm sure they would be interested to learn about pathological websites that break the functionality of the plugin.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll do that and report back if I get an answer.